# Angular multiple ngif else passing parameter in template

Tags: angular, angular-template

Is it possible to do two ngIf in angular.html?

An example:

```
if(1=2){
}else{
    if(){
    }
}
```

I need to make two checks.

Check the teacher's restriction if it is false to check the availability of the classroom.

follows an example of my code. I'm new to angular and I do not know how everything works.

```
   <td *ngIf="!restricaoSegUm; else templateName" *ngIf="!restricaoSalaSegUm; else sala" [dragula]='"another-bag"' [dragulaModel]='segUm'>
      <div [@resultadoAnimacao]="animationsState" class="cursor-pointer"  *ngFor='let s1 of segUm' (dblclick)="removeNumbers(s1,this.segUm)">{{s1?.no_diciplinas}}</div>
    </td>

<ng-template #templateName >
    <td style="background-color: rgb(244, 67, 54);"></td>
</ng-template>
<ng-template-sala #sala>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(244, 146, 54);"></td>
</ng-template-sala>
```

Comment: Just use the logical AND operator '&&' like so `*ngif="!teachersRestriction && classRoomAvailable;"` should work

Comment: @than The problem is that each restriction will have its background-color. Teachers color red. classRoom color orange.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, those restrictions are only to alter background color, you still want whatever is in div to show up? and if my assumption is right here then you should use [ngStyle] instead

Comment: more or less, I need to change the color and cancel the drag and drop ([dragula]). so, cuz of this I did it with ngIf

Comment: have a look at the answer I have provided, if it still doesn't solve your problem then I would suggest you provide a plunker example and state all possible logical use cases.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of the structural directive `*ngIf` to accomplish what you're doing.  You could try and work with `ngTemplateOutlet` and `ngTemplateOutletContext` to help structure the markup so it's more readable.

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="(statement) ? if : else"
              [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ data: { key: value, values: [...], ... } }"></ng-container>

<ng-template #if>
  <div>...</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #else 
             let-data="data" 
             let-values="values" 
             let-...="'...'">

  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="(statement) ? innerIf : innerElse"></ng-container>

  <ng-template #innerIf>
    <td [ngClass]="'text-danger': data.key === 'something'">{{ data.key }}</td>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #innerElse>
    <td *ngFor="let value in values">{{ value }}</td>
  </ng-template>

</ng-template>
```

Regardless of what method (`*ngIf`, `*ngTemplateOutlet`, ...) you choose with this kind of complexity in your template it seems like the best solution would be creating more stateless components.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap 2 *ngIf inside each other.

so like

```
<div ng-if="myVar">
<div ng-if="myOtherVar">
<!--
Your code
-->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should not be putting 2 *ngIfs but rather do this instead `*ngIf="conditions; then thenBlock; else elseBlock"`.
- In `conditions` section, check for teacher restriction, once in the templateName block then you determine which background color to use.

Try this:

```
<td *ngIf="!restricaoSegUm; else templateName" 
    [dragula]='"another-bag"' [dragulaModel]='segUm'>
    <div [@resultadoAnimacao]="animationsState" class="cursor-pointer"  *ngFor='let s1 of segUm' (dblclick)="removeNumbers(s1,this.segUm)">{{s1?.no_diciplinas}}</div>
</td>

<ng-template #templateName >
    <td [ngStyle]="restricaoSalaSegUm ? { 'background-color': 'rgb(244, 67, 54)' } : { 'background-color': 'rgb(244, 146, 54);' }">
        <div [@resultadoAnimacao]="animationsState" class="cursor-pointer"  *ngFor='let s1 of segUm' (dblclick)="removeNumbers(s1,this.segUm)">{{s1?.no_diciplinas}}</div>
    </td>
</ng-template>
```

I don't understand what your logical conditions evaluate to, hopefully I have pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You can put both `conditions` inside one `*ngFor` and btw it's incorrect to use 2 `*ngFor` on a single element:

```
<td *ngIf="!restricaoSegUm && !restricaoSalaSegUm; else templateName" [dragula]='"another-bag"' [dragulaModel]='segUm'>
```

Comment: This won't work, because [dragula] is not a property of td.